# jsonpath find all object(restassured)

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

This is my JSON :

```
[
{
    "id": 9741962,
    "name": "getName",
    "isActive": true
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "New",
    "isActive": true
}
]
```

I want to get all the object that has the name :getName using jsonPath
how can I do it using JsonPath (the onw that comes with rest assured)

I try this one

```
JsonPath.with(jsonResponse).get("findAll { a -> a.name == getName  }");
```

but I am getting Error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such property: sdfsdf for class: Script1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

OK I found it, needed to add apostrophes.

`JsonPath.with(jsonResponse).get("findAll { a -> a.name == 'getName' }");`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set param. Try

```
JsonPath.with(jsonResponse).param("name", "getName").get("findAll { a -> a.name == name  }")
```

Comment: the param is only for version 2.3.2

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: we have version 2.3.1 of both restassured and jsonPath.