# Exception "No such field: age for class: java.util.HashMap$Node" when search via "findAll" in response body

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Good day.
I try to validate a value of the "name" field in JSON response via "findAll" with the known value of the "age" field.
Unfortunately, I get an exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such field: age for class: java.util.HashMap$Node".
I know there are other ways to validate this field, but my goal - validate via "findAll" command. Thanks in advance.
The response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private, max-age=31536000
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2021 12:28:12 GMT
Display: staticcontent_sol
Expires: Thu, 03 Feb 2022 12:28:11 GMT
Host-Header: c2hhcmVkLmJsdWVob3N0LmNvbQ==
Referrer-Policy: 
Response: 200
Server: nginx/1.16.0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Origin
X-Ezoic-Cdn: Miss
X-Middleton-Display: staticcontent_sol
X-Middleton-Response: 200
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 60
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 58
X-Sol: pub_site
Content-Length: 118

{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "name": "Zion",
        "salary": 12000,
        "age": 23
    },
    "message": "Successfully! Record has been updated."
}
```

The code:

```
package toolsqaexamples;    

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;    

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

public class PutReq {

    @Test
    public void putRequestUpdateRecords() {

        int empid = 15410;

        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1";
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
            
        JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
        requestParams.put("name", "Zion");
        requestParams.put("age", 23);
        requestParams.put("salary", 12000);

        request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
            
        request.body(requestParams.toJSONString());    
        
        Response response = request.put("/update/" + empid);  
            
        response.then().body("data.findAll { data -> data.@age == 23 }.name", equalTo("Zion"));

    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
C:\Users\Sergey\.jdks\openjdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe...
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/C:/Users/Sergey/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.15/groovy-2.4.15.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such field: age for class: groovy.util.slurpersupport.Node
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:238)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:250)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.xml.XMLAssertion.getResult(XMLAssertion.groovy:99)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.xml.XMLAssertion$getResult.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.xml.XMLAssertion.getResult(XMLAssertion.groovy:106)
    at io.restassured.internal.assertion.Assertion$getResult.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at io.restassured.assertion.BodyMatcher.validate(BodyMatcher.groovy:94)
    at io.restassured.assertion.BodyMatcher$validate$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:144)
    at io.restassured.assertion.BodyMatcherGroup$_validate_closure2.doCall(BodyMatcherGroup.groovy:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:434)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3287)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3257)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$67.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at io.restassured.assertion.BodyMatcherGroup.validate(BodyMatcherGroup.groovy:47)
    at io.restassured.assertion.BodyMatcherGroup$validate$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:144)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:481)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:656)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.content(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:277)
    at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$content$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:193)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.body(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:260)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.body(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:274)
    at toolsqaexamples.PutReq.putRequestUpdateRecords(PutReq.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Updated: log attached

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace.  It will help us to figure out what is causing the problem.

Comment: @StephenC, log added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I could find is you can not use `findAll()` here. Because `findAll()` is used on Collections. Check [Groovy documentation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll()). And also check [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-assured-groovy).

If you have a array in your json response, then you can use `findAll()` to get the answer.

Example:
If your json response is as follows;

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "dataSet": [
    {
      "name": "Zion",
      "salary": 12000,
      "age": 23
    },
    {
      "name": "name_2",
      "salary": 13000,
      "age": 24
    }
  ],
  "message": "Successfully! Record has been updated."
}
```

You can use `findAll()` to get the result. But `findAll()` will return an array. So you have to get the first value of it.

```
RestAssured.given().when().get().then()
       .body("dataSet.findAll{a -> a.age == 23 }.name[0]", equalTo("Zion"));
```

Refer the accepted answers of following Stackoverflow questions as well.

[Groovy - Parse JSON where only certain values exists in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102892/groovy-parse-json-where-only-certain-values-exists-in-response)

[jsonpath find all object(restassured)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061500/jsonpath-find-all-objectrestassured)